# Estou tentando listar os pedidos de um cliente mas tem um erro no DAO o qual não consigo identificar

Tags: java, jsf, nullpointerexception

**Botão que chama a página que lista os pedidos:**

```
<p:commandButton value="Avançar" id="avancar" action="#{clienteMB.avancarPedido(pedido)}" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" ajax="false"/>
```

**Método Avançar pedido no Bean Gerenciável:**

```
public String avancarPedido(Cliente cliente) {
        setPedidos(getPedidoDAO().consultarPedidoporCliente(cliente));
        this.cliente = cliente;
        return "mostrarpedidos";
}
```

**DAO**

```
public List<Pedido> consultarPedidoporCliente(Cliente cliente) {

        List<Pedido> pedidos = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Connection connection = new Conexao().conectar();
            String sql = "select id, data from pedido where id_cliente = ?";
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1,cliente.getId());
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){

                int id = rs.getInt(1);
                int data = rs.getInt(2);
                Pedido p = new Pedido(id, data, cliente);
                pedidos.add(p);
            }
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            connection.close();
            return pedidos;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            return pedidos;
        }                
    }
```

**Tela mostrarpedidos**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Pedidos</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form> 
            <p:panel header="Pedidos">

                <p:dataTable var="pedido" value="#{clienteMB.pedidos}">
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{pedido.id}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{pedido.data}" />
                </p:column>


            </p:dataTable>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**Erro**

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DAO.PedidoDAO.consultarPedidoporCliente(PedidoDAO.java:29)
    at BEANS.ClienteMB.avancarPedido(ClienteMB.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: Qual o erro que é mostrado?

Comment: at DAO.PedidoDAO.consultarPedidoporCliente(PedidoDAO.java:29)
Linha29:ps.setInt(1,cliente.getId());

at BEANS.ClienteMB.avancarPedido(ClienteMB.java:41)
Linha41:setPedidos(getPedidoDAO().consultarPedidoporCliente(cliente));

Comment: Você pode editar seu post e incluir a stack inteira com o erro?

Comment: Coloquei a stack inteira ali

Comment: Tem uma `NullPointerException` acontecendo na linha 29 da classe `PedidoDAO.java`. O que tem nessa linha? É isso aqui? `ps.setInt(1,cliente.getId());` se for, então `cliente` está vindo `null`.

Comment: Eu debugei agora e vi que tá vindo null mesmo, mas em que parte do código ele tá se perdendo ?

Comment: Achei o erro, estava passando o objeto errado no botão